# Find adjacent tiles in a two-dimensional grid

Tags: javascript, performance, grid-layout

I have a two-dimensional grid, in which all tiles are defined by two coordinates x and y. I'm storing the tiles in an array like this `var tiles = [];`. Each tile is an object with an `x` and `y` property:

```
Tile = {
   x: ...,
   y: ...
}
```

For drawing purposes (canvas) I want to find out which tiles are adjacent to each other. I could do that by looping through each element and check if it is adjacent. Since that would take n^n number of accesses I don't think this is the right way to do it. I think there would be a more efficient algorithm.

I also thought that maybe storing the data in a different way would help, but again, I wouldn't know how.

Comment: Well, from a generic perspective this looks like an issue you can investigate by learning big O notation and how it relates to data storage types in computer science. That said, it looks like you're going to have to do it this way you're thinking of.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have 2 ways to create a grid :

- Using a 2 dimensional Array which must be the easier thing for a grid
- Store adjacent Tile of a Tile in it with something like that :

  ```
  var tile0 = {
    x:0, y:1
  }

  var tile1 = {
    x:1,y:1, tileLeft : tile0
  }
  ```

It can be useful if you want to create Pentagonal or Hexagonal... grid, ofcourse create your grid automatically with a for loop.

**EDIT**

A two dimensional array is simply an Array of Array

```
var arr = new Array()
for(var i = 0 ; i < 10 ; i++){
    arr[i] = new Array()
}
```

Now you can set value like in a grid, for example :

```
arr[0][2] = {x:2,y:2}  //It's a bit useless since indexes can be use for x and y
```

In that case, i have 10 Array stored in one Array so :

```
arr[10][0]
```

Will return following error : Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property '2' of undefined, because index of arr are only define between 0 and 9.

Comment: Can you explain how a two-dimensional array would work and be used here?

Comment: My problem is that the grid is infinite and only some tiles are defined. So the first method seems more fitting for me. But since I would need to also save and load the data it looks a bit difficult to realise.

Comment: It's javascript object, you can store them in a JSON so in a mongoDB database too, find a proper way to create your tile seem harder problem than store and load them.

Your problem depend on size of your data, how much time you can wait to load the data...

Comment: Thank you for you help. I think I'll map the two coordinates to a single unique integer that I can store in a one-dimensional array (which is less confusing to me) and additionally store that in the individual tiles.

Answer (score 0):

With your data construct I can't see a way to check for all adjacent tiles without accessing each tile.

The "tried and true" two dimensional grid data construct would be...a simple two dimensional array. Then you can access tiles directly by their coordinates.

Comment: Can you explain how a two-dimensional array would work and be used here?